# How to set a local variable from new function in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have a function with a variable. I need to run code from a string to modify that variable. How would I set a local variable from `new Function()` or something similar?

```js
function alertNumber() {
  var number = 5;
  var f = new Function("number = 4");
  f();
  console.log("local " + number); //should alert 4
  console.log("window " + window.number); //instead of the local variable, it sets the property to the window
}
alertNumber();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `new Function`, [it's not possible.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/Function)

> However, unlike eval (which may have access to the local scope), the Function constructor creates functions which execute in the global scope only.

You would need

```js
function alertNumber() {
  var number = 5;
  eval("number = 4");
  console.log("local " + number); //should alert 4
}
alertNumber();
```

(though having to do this in the first place is quite suspicious - if it were me, I'd consider hard if there were really no alternatives first)

Answer (score 1):

Just create a new function that modifies the number and then returns the result of the modified number:

```js
// This should fix your problem

function modifyNumber(number) {
  return number = 4
}

function alertNumber() {
  var number = 5
  number = modifyNumber(number)
  console.log("local " + number) // outputs "local 4"
}
```